# artificial neural network in octave

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I'm having trouble on an easy exercise about an artificial neural network with 2 features, a hidden layer of 5 neurons and two possible outputs (0 or 1).
My `X` matrix is a 51x2 matrix, and `y` is a 51x1 vector.

I know I'm not supposed to do the `while E>1` but I wanted to see if eventually my error would be lower than 1

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong. My error doesn't seem to lower (around 1.5 no matter how much iterations I'm doing). Do you see in the code where I am doing a mistake? I'm supposed to use gradient descent.

```
function [E, v,w] = costFunction(X, y,alpha1,alpha2)


[m n] = size(X);

E = 1;


v = 2*rand(5,3)-1;
w = 2*rand(2,6)-1;

grad_v=zeros(size(v));
grad_w=zeros(size(w));

K = 2;

E = 2;

while E> 1
        a1 = [ones(m,1) X];
        z2 = a1 * v';
        a2 = sigmoid(z2);
        a2 = [ones(size(a2,1),1),a2];
        z3 = a2 * w';
        h = sigmoid(z3);

        cost = sum((-y.*log(h)) - ((1-y).*log(1-h)),2);
        E = (1/m)*sum(cost);

        Delta1=0;
        Delta2=0;

        for t = 1:m
            a1 = [1;X(t,:)'];
            z2 = v * a1;
            a2 = sigmoid(z2);
            a2 = [1;a2];
            z3 = w * a2;
            a3 = sigmoid(z3);

            d3 = a3 -  y(t,:)';

            d2 = (w(:,2:end)'*d3).*sigmoidGradient(z2);

            Delta2 += (d3*a2');
            Delta1 += (d2*a1');
        end

        grad_v = (1/m) * Delta1;
        grad_w = (1/m) * Delta2;

        v -= alpha1 * grad_v;
        w -= alpha2 * grad_w;
    end
end
```

Comment: There is no question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site, it is required to ask a **question**, not post a lot of code and give a description of it. Please ask an actual question, so that a) we know what you want and b) so that you can receive an answer.

Comment: If the error is not normalized, its magnitude means nothing. If your values are on the order of billions, an error of 1.5 is the best in the world. if your values are in the decimals, it meas you are doing it very bad. You can not  just look at the value of the error independently and make conclusions

Comment: Ok i see, but since i had an error of 1.5 with only one iteration, i assumed it would lower with many...

Comment: @VictorBigand if you are doing gradient descend, it should lower each iteration, even if it is a very tiny tiny bit, unles you reached the minima (which doesnt mean it reached error=0)

Comment: @AnderBiguri i know, that's why i'm looking for help :) I've already done GD with linear regression or classification, and obviously I'm missing something here that I can see due to my lack of experience ..

Comment: Provide example inputs and expected outputs. You've provided the code, but not a way to reproduce what your results are.